# Give Role when a member joins the voice channel. discord.js

Tags: discord.js

Im trying to make discord.js code. When a member joins the voice channnel I want the bot to give them a role, when the member leaves, i want the role to be removed. thanks for your help.

```
  const newChannelID = newState.channelID;
  const oldChannelID = oldState.channelID;

  if (oldChannelID === "835280102764838942"){
    member.send('role given');
    let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.id === "835279162293747774");
    member.roles.add(835279162293747774);

  } else if(newChannelID === "835280102764838942"){
    member.send('role removed');
    member.roles.remove(835279162293747774);

  }
})
```

Comment: I can see a few things wrong with your code, but what is the problem you're actually trying to get help for? Your question is a bit vague about what you need assistance with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of things you need to clean up in your code. I'm going to assume you're using the `voiceStateUpdate` event to trigger your command.

Most importantly, (logic-wise) you actually need to flip-flop the way you add and remove roles. Currently, the general code states that if the user left the voice channel (thus `oldChannelID` = actual vc ID), then it would actually give the user a role. This seems to be the opposite of your intention, thus you'd simply swap out the code in each `if/else if` statement.

Second, the way you're assigning roles and adding them is incorrect. I'd recommend [this resource](https://anidiots.guide/understanding/roles) for more info.

Third, you cannot access `message` if you were indeed using `voiceStateUpdate` as your event, since it only emits an `oldState` and a `newState`.

Lastly, you need to designate a text channel to send the message to. In my code, I manually grabbed the ID of the channel I wanted and plugged it into the code. You'll have to do the same by replacing the number strings I have with your own specific ones.

With that being said, here's the correct modified code:

```js
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldState, newState) => {
    const txtChannel = client.channels.cache.get('803359668054786118'); //manually input your own channel
    const newChannelID = newState.channelID;
    const oldChannelID = oldState.channelID;

    if (oldChannelID === "800743802074824747") { //manually put the voice channel ID
        txtChannel.send('role removed');
        let role = newState.guild.roles.cache.get("827306356842954762"); //added this
        newState.member.roles.remove(role).catch(console.error);
    } else if (newChannelID === "800743802074824747") {
        txtChannel.send('role given');
        let role = oldState.guild.roles.cache.get("827306356842954762"); //change this somewhat
        oldState.member.roles.add(role).catch(console.error); //adding a catch method is always good practice
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks so much! It seems its not working though 

Comment: You will have to substitute the number strings for your own channel and role IDs. The ones used in the example code were my own ID strings.

Comment: My bad, I forgot to add a check to see if the user stayed in the VC but started to stream. To fix that, you just have to add an `if (oldChannelID == newChannelID) return;` before your other two `if` conditions.